# Hub Site Translation not working when switching to another language

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, navigation, react, hub-site

We have a hub site with navigation enabled and also MUI setup for Arabic language. Each item in the menu has the translations. When user switches from English To Arabic, the whole UI experience changes except the Navigation. Changing the language requires the users to clear the browser Cache which is not a good experience. Even Ctrl + F5 do not helped here.

Is there any way to force clear cache or force my portal to reload changed MUI Navigation?

**Environment:**
SharePoint Online with SPFX React

Answer (score 0):

Hub navigation is cached in several different places. There is no out-of-the-box way to clear them all, only one third-party product does it.